# Как сделать респавн rigidbody объектов?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

В чём суть, у меня на сцене имеются различные Rigidbody объекты, игрок их может толькать, поворачивать и делать всё что захочется, а также игрок может умирать и возрождаться и я нигде не могу найти, как сделать так, что бы при возрождении все rigidbody объекты вставали в своё исходное положение

Comment: Что значит "нигде не могу найти"? Обычно разработчики могут поразмышлять  и решить проблему сами на основе рассуждений и умозаключений))) Вообще - обозначьте все объекты одним тегом, к примеру. В начале уровня найдите их всех и сложите в список или словарь. (объект - position). Когда игрок реинициализиуется - пробегайтесь по словарю и восстанавливайте у объекта сохранённый position. Всё

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, мечешь бисер перед свиньями. Это тег `unity3d`. Тут постоянно "начинающие", не зная даже основ языка, "учат unity".

Comment: @АлексейШиманский лучше сохранять весь Transform - вместе с positiom, rotation, scale...

Answer (score 0):

1. Задаете объектам, которые будете ставить на место, какой-нибудь тег (допустим ToBase)
2. Создаете скрипт, отвечающий за восстановление объектам (условно ObjectController), и вешаете его на какой-нибудь объект
3. В нем объявляете массив с вектором позиции для восстановления и массив с объектами, у которых восстанавливать:

   ```
   private Vector3[] _basePosArray;
   private GameObject[] _baseObjectsArray;
   ```
4. Находите объекты для восстановления по тегу и засовываете их в массив, а оттуда уже наполняете массив позиций:

   ```
   void Start()
   {
      _baseObjectsArray = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ToBase");
      for (int i = 0; i < _basePosArray; i++)
      {
          _basePosArray[i] = _baseObjectsArray[i].transform.position; 
      }
   }
   ```
5. Добавляем метод восстановления базовой позиции:

   ```
   public void RespawnObjects()
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < _basePosArray; i++)
       {
          _baseObjectsArray[i].transform.position = _basePosArray[i]; 
       }
   }
   ```
6. Далее в классе вашего персонажа объявляем наш недавно созданный класс, а затем в инспекторе накидываем туда объект на котором висит скрипт с ним:

   ```
    public ObjectController controller;
   ```
7. И последнее в коде нашего персонажа при его смерти вызываем респавн объектов:

   ```
    void PlayerDie()
    {
        controller.RespawnObject();
    }
   ```